# Native timestamp on wp_options option

Tags: database, options

Does anyone know if the `wp_options` table have modified timestamps for their options? I have an option that has an object as the option value as shown below:

[image]

The "Access Token" within the option value object gets updated frequently and I'd like to check when "instagram" has been modified and return the timestamp.

If not, would you say it would be easier to just set an object key as modified and save the current time?

Thanks all! I'd like to do it as native as possible with `get_option()` or such before I save an extra key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "updated" column in the `wp_options` table.

```
mysql> describe wp_options;
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id    | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option_name  | varchar(191)    | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| option_value | longtext        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| autoload     | varchar(20)     | NO   | MUL | yes     |                |
+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

If you need to know when an option was updated, you'll need to inject that information into the option itself. If you're managing the code, it's easy enough: just add a new field to the array that you're saving.

eg:

```
update_option(
    'instagram',
    array(
        'username' => 'semirtravels',
        'user_id'  => '{your user ID}',
        // ...
        'last_updated' => time(),
   )
);
```

If not, you might be able to intercept it using the [`pre_update_option_{$option}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_update_option_option/) filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_instagram', 'wpse_400857_add_updated_time', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Adds the current time() to the value of the `instagram` option.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value     The option's value.
 * @param  mixed  $old_value The option's previous value.
 * @param  string $option    The option name.
 * @return mixed             The filtered option value.
 */ 
function wpse_400857_add_updated_time( $value, $old_value, $option ) {
    $value['last_updated'] = time();
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! I was able to just push the last_updated to the associative array and infuse it within get_option.